# Eclipse CDT "Path must include project and resource name"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, build-error

I've been banging my head against a brick wall with this, so any help will be much appreciated :)

I have created two projects with the following structure.

1. There is one source folder under C:\ide\xxx\source
2. There is a project folder under C:\ide\xxx\build1
3. There is a project folder under C:\ide\xxx\build2
4. Both build1 and build2 include the linked folder C:\ide\xxx\source using the variable MYBUILD_ROOT="C:\ide\xxx".

build2 compiles just fine using the internal builder. However, build1 doesn't even start to build because it reports

```
> **** Rebuild of configuration Release for project CoreMarkTs1 ****
> 
> **** Internal Builder is used for build               **** 
> Build error
> Path must include project and resource
> name: /build1
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The question is 3 years old, I know, but just in case someone stumbles upon it with the same problem (as I did)

This thread might answer the problem: [Eclipse CDT Invalid Project Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307367/eclipse-cdt-invalid-project-path).
In case The "Discovery Options" isn't there, this other thread explains how to make it reappear: [Discovery Options in Eclipse C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412100/discovery-options-in-eclipse-c-c)

In my case, this manipulation didn't do the trick. I figured afterwards that I had a malformed path in my loaded DLL list (Project Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Cross G++ Linker > Miscellaneous > Other objects). I corrected the faulty path to a DLL and now the "Path must include project and resource" error is gone (Now I've just got regular errors :P)

Comment: Thanks.  I like it when someone documents their footwork.  Especially when it pointed me to solve my problem... :)