# Discovery Options in Eclipse C/C++

Tags: eclipse, gcc, arm

I'm not a programmer by trade and just recently decided to delve into using Eclipse C/C++ to program an ARM microcontroller and my problem is setting up the IDE.  Basically, I'm following the direction from here: (https://openwsn.atlassian.net/wiki/display/OW/GNU+ARM) but after trying to run

```
int main(void){

int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
   i++;
}
return i;

}
```

I get this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq9m1.png

Which means that somewhere in the "Discovery Options" I've invoked 'arm-elf-gcc'.  The problem is I don't know how to get to "Discovery Options" in the newest version of Eclipse C/C++ Kepler SR1.  Can someone tell me where I can change it so I instead invoke 'arm-none-eabi-gcc'?  When I go to Project Properties its no longer under C/C++ Build

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Kepler hides "Discovery Options" by default. Go to Window->Preferences-> C/C++ > Property Pages Settings and check display discovery option page. Then, open your project preferences and change arm-elf-gcc to arm-none-eabi-gcc like the rest.

Comment: took me half a day to find this post, T H A N K   Y O U ! ! !

Answer (score 1):

As you probably noticed, there is a new version of the [GNU ARM Eclipse Plug-in](http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/blog/) available, which greatly simplifies toolchain PATH management.

Could you try it?

In case you still have problems, please use the GNU ARM Eclipse Plug-in [support tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuarmeclipse/support-requests/).