# Eclipse says errors but no error

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-juno

At the end of *Run **X.exe**(the **Play** button)* operation Eclipse asks *Errors exists in project. Continue launch?* but there is nothing red, no errors in project, it also compiles the project. Also if I say yes it launches the newly compiled executable with no errors.

At the end of *Build Project (the wrench button)* operation, it does **not** say ***errors found*** and also compiles successfully.

This suddenly started to happen as the project grew.

Using Windows and MinGW 4.7.2.

**EDIT**

*Read comments*

Now the error has changed. It says *Errors exist in a required project. Continue to launch?*
Yet it still compiles successfully, and there is still no errors in *Problems display*.

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing written in the "problems" view?

Comment: It just has 30~ warnings.
Also, I have tried _clean_.

Comment: Try to fix them and see if the problem persists. Btw, ignoring warnings outright is never a good thing.

Comment: They are there due to a library I am using. Almost half of them is about _in-class declaration of non-static variables only in C++11_ thing.

Comment: There is a _warning_ I could not understand: 
_Invalid project path: Duplicate path entries found (/testProject [Include path] isSystemInclude:true includePath:K:/MinGW/BOOST/boost_1_52_0), path: [/testProject]._

Comment: This may very well be the cause. Here's a SO Q&A that may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307367/eclipse-cdt-invalid-project-path

Comment: That turned out to be the problem indeed. Type it in as an answer so I can mark as resolved?

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark the issue as resolved. You'd know better how you solved it exactly. :)

Comment: It came back for no reason. Now I don't have any weird warnings either. And it also keeps rebuilding everything even if I change a little change in a class _.cpp_

Comment: Switched to QtCreator and am living happily. Apparently Eclipse internal builder & output parser is broken.

Comment: I have the same error...