# run android Cocos2d-x project in eclipse not working , Invalid project path: Include path not found

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

Im new to cocos2d-x and I a face issue while tring to run my app.

what I did is :

- Download android adt Bundle (eclpise + android SDK).
- Download android-ndk-r9d
- Download cocos2d-x 2.2.3

I extract them all , and I create new project using create_project.py
then , I import the project in eclipse and the (android platform library which known as libcocos2dx)

btw, I install the android sdk 8 and 15 and I set the NDK_ROOT to the ndk path.

The problme is when i run the app , an alert shows and said "unfortunately 'appname' has stopped" something like that

then , I notice this warning which said

> Invalid project path: Include path not found
>   (/opt/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/include).

I wonder what is the problem cause the app work before for me. but then It can at run at all.

btw , I use Ubuntu and Max OSX and I have same problem.

Comment: This will seem like a dumb question, but have you checked that the content at that path actually exists? Also, since this question isn't cocos2d-x specific (afaik), you can refer to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307367/eclipse-cdt-invalid-project-path).

Comment: yes I did , all paths are set correctly. except this warning apper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx ,finally, It work form me now. 
Maybee the problem that I use the cocos2d-x folder as workplace for eclipse projects

Comment: Would you please mark your question as answered or delete the whole thread

Answer (score 0):

Use other version of the Android NDK for Mac OSX the 9 have some issues with cocos2d-x.

Currently I'm using the Android NDK r8d on works well.